# Seagull Traffic Generator. AVP length

Tags: diameter-protocol

Is there a way to set AVP length forcefully in Seagull Diameter Traffic Generator?
I have set it in base_cc.xml but it didn't help, AVP length stayed the same as it was before. Here's is how my cfg looks like:

```
<define name="User-Equipment-Info-Value" type="OctetString">
  <setfield name="avp-code" value="460"></setfield>
  <setfield name="flags" value="64"></setfield>
  <setfield name="avp-length" value="16"></setfield>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to set length in define tag after setting type:
like this in xml file :

```
<define name="abc" type="Enumerated" length="32">
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.